# SharePoint filter lookup field, based on another field in the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column

I am using SharePoint online and am having trouble with the formulas since they are not exactly like Excel or InfoPath.

This custom list I am creating has a lookup column for office locations and I want the field to filter only the offices in the same state as the team member. Can someone help me with this, details below. I hope I explained this right.

Lookup List (Office Locations)
 - Columns in list
    1. LocationID
    2. State

List (Custom List)
 - Columns in list
    1. Preferred Location
    2. State

Answer (score 0):

Dannielle, I believe you will have to do it progamatically. Ideally, you should get the "state" of the user (using some API maybe), and then filter the list based on that state and then display it. There are many ways to do this and perhaps you can do it with javascript.